# What are the major differences between 1st and 2nd edition Gamma World?

Tags: edition-comparison, gamma-world, gamma-world-1e-2e

Or are there any?  I'm trying to figure out which to run.  I see that 3rd and 4th are pretty different, but could someone give me a run down on 1st/2nd?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Certainly long winded and does not detail rules changes as such but [Gamma World: Over 30 years of I have no idea what is going on.](https://web.archive.org/web/20120113051319/http://www.headinjurytheater.com/gammaworld.htm) covers the evolution of the game. It should give you the differences in feel between the two editions.